# Does the node.js callback mimic the java accept socket?

Tags: java, node.js, sockets

I have written some code in node.js a while back and I used the magic of sockets to accomplish what I wanted.

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){ //code });
```

I understood from this code that the socket given as the argument to the callback is the socket that just connected and just gets served the code into the callback. Recently however I have tried to move a bit into java and I have met this code:

```
ServerSocket client_socket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket socket = client_socket.accept();
```

My question now is weather the accept function will fetch me the socket that just connected exactly the way that the callback would do it in node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the same. [#accept()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) blocks till a connection is made. A solution to run the code asynchronously, is in [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
 class NetworkService implements Runnable {
   private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
   private final ExecutorService pool;

   public NetworkService(int port, int poolSize)
       throws IOException {
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
     pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
   }

   public void run() { // run the service
     try {
       for (;;) {
         pool.execute(new Handler(serverSocket.accept()));
       }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
       pool.shutdown();
     }
   }
 }

 class Handler implements Runnable {
   private final Socket socket;
   Handler(Socket socket) { this.socket = socket; }
   public void run() {
     // read and service request on socket
   }
 }
```

If you run the NetworkService in another executorservice it won't block, and execute the code in `poolSize` seperate threads. This different from node.js which is single-threaded.

You could also call [getChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#getChannel%28%29) and use it with a [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) to keep things non blocking.

Comment: Quick question about the ExecutorService. Does it create a new thread for every socket that connects and then gives it as an argument for a runnable?

Comment: No, `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)` creates 4 threads. The Handler-runnables are automagically run on one of those 4 threads. The handler constructor takes the socket as argument, and can use it in its run() method. If the handlers are slow, and 5 connections come in, the 5th will have to wait till one of the previous 4 finishes.